# we want to give every Spotify user a chance to win a competition if they add track to one of their public playlists

Tags: api, spotify

As an artist with a track on Spotify can I get a list of ALL public playlists that the track has been added to? (and the user contact details – e.g. Email - who created the playlist)

Comment: What do the docs tell you?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with any public API (especially the email address part - it'd be a privacy nightmare!).

If you want to set up a promotional thing like this with Spotify you'll need to go through Spotify's Label Relations, which means speaking to your record label.

Comment: Thank you, it's a brand promotional piece, would I still go through the Label Relation's or through Brand support? Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm just a developer - I've no idea, sorry.